# R: How do I stop the adorn functions in janitor from altering a secondary character column?

Tags: r, dplyr, janitor

Below is an example of what I'm experiencing

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

x <- data_frame(c1=c('a','a','b','b'),
                c2=c('a','b','c','d'),
                c3=runif(4,0,10),
                c4=runif(4,10,20),
                c5=runif(4,20,100))

x %>%
  adorn_totals(c('col')) %>%
  adorn_percentages('row') %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
  adorn_ns('front')
```

Running this code provides the following output:

```
 c1    c2                c3               c4               c5              Total
  a a (a) 1.0495149  (1.2%) 12.78693 (15.0%) 71.48728 (83.8%)  85.32373 (100.0%)
  a b (b) 0.9217471  (0.9%) 19.71064 (20.1%) 77.67327 (79.0%)  98.30566 (100.0%)
  b c (c) 9.0695540 (19.4%) 14.39917 (30.8%) 23.32479 (49.8%)  46.79351 (100.0%)
  b d (d) 8.9398517  (7.8%) 18.53542 (16.1%) 87.43437 (76.1%) 114.90965 (100.0%)
```

As you can see, column `c2` is just another character column and thus shouldn't be impacted by the `adorn_` functions, but as I go from `adorn_pct_formatting` to `adorn_ns` it mutates that column in an unexpected way.

Does anyone know how to prevent this while maintaining my same general approach below; meaning that I continue to use the `adorn_` functions from `janitor`?

I'm aware and capable of writing code to calculate and paste the N's and %s into each specific column manually but I'm looking specifically for a way to do it using the functions provided here, if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try to look at the source code to find out what happened https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/blob/master/R/adorn_ns.R. Otherwise open an issue on the package GitHub page

Comment: you could try `left_join`ing the outcomes to each other...

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a mechanism to prevent Janitor adorning the character columns.

There is also [a bug logged](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/issues/195) on the Janitor repo where the adornment of character columns is discussed.

My solution was to process the character column after the adorn function byt splitting the string using stringr::strsplit.

```
library(stringr)

df %>% 
mutate(character_col = sapply(strsplit(character_col, "\\s\\(" ), [, 1))
```

I hope this is useful to others who come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed in janitor v2.0.0.  Character columns are left as-is by `adorn_ns()`:

```
x %>%
    adorn_totals(c('col')) %>%
    adorn_percentages('row') %>%
    adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
    adorn_ns('front')

 c1 c2               c3               c4               c5             Total
  a  a 1.294509  (1.5%) 10.60898 (12.5%) 72.87039 (86.0%) 84.77388 (100.0%)
  a  b 6.557902 (11.2%) 19.27799 (32.9%) 32.73041 (55.9%) 58.56630 (100.0%)
  b  c 5.336008  (7.8%) 17.68432 (25.9%) 45.20563 (66.3%) 68.22596 (100.0%)
  b  d 4.984140  (8.6%) 16.18887 (27.8%) 37.05183 (63.6%) 58.22485 (100.0%)
```

You can also control which columns to adorn with the `...` argument.